# Merge guest account with registered account

Tags: support, status-completed

Can an admin please merge my guest account with my StackExchange account?

Guest: https://serverfault.com/users/104148/john
StackExchange: https://serverfault.com/users/116123/serverbloke

I have added a comment in the Bio of the StackEx account to confirm it's me.

I did try to put this on meta but it won't let me - need an account to post, and when trying to post from the StackEx account it needs 5 rep.

Comment: Just to confirm, you want the `john` account merged with the `serverbloke` account ?

Comment: @lain yes, I want ditch `john` and keep `serverbloke`, but I want to transfer `john`'s questions and rep to `serverbloke`. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your john account has been merged into the serverbloke account.

Comment: Thanks lain that's just what I needed.